# How to export trained tensorflow 2 model to tflite?

Tags: java, android-studio, tensorflow

I have trained my **tensorflow 2.2** model and have all the checkpoints as well as the automatically generated saved_model.pb file in the same folder. My end goal is to run the trained .tflite model on the **rev robotics control hub**. But, I can't find a way to convert or export the trained model. I've tried to use this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ofuUdCDppc&t=587s, and I am able to get a .tflite file, but *I have no way to test if's good*, and when I run it on the rev control hub, **it just crashes immediately** (the same code, with some mandatory tweaks works just fine with tf1, but due to a lot of reasons, I can't and don't want to switch back to tf1). I hope this is a problem with the way I convert my model to .tflite, but it can also be, that I am missing something in my android studio code for the rev hub (in theory it should support tf2, because it literally has a parameter: **isModelTensorFlow2**). If you have the time, I have linked the robot controller repository (https://github.com/FIRST-Tech-Challenge/FtcRobotController/releases/tag/v7.1) and our code, which runs the model on the rev hub:

```
package org.firstinspires.ftc.teamcode;

import com.qualcomm.robotcore.eventloop.opmode.LinearOpMode;
import com.qualcomm.robotcore.eventloop.opmode.TeleOp;
import java.util.List;
import org.firstinspires.ftc.robotcore.external.ClassFactory;
import org.firstinspires.ftc.robotcore.external.hardware.camera.WebcamName;
import org.firstinspires.ftc.robotcore.external.navigation.VuforiaLocalizer;
import org.firstinspires.ftc.robotcore.external.tfod.TFObjectDetector;
import org.firstinspires.ftc.robotcore.external.tfod.Recognition;

@TeleOp(name = "AI", group = "Concept")
public class FTC_WEBCAM extends LinearOpMode {
    private static final String TFOD_MODEL_ASSET = "model.tflite";
    private static final String LABEL_FIRST_ELEMENT = "1 ball";
    //private static final String LABEL_SECOND_ELEMENT = "Skystone";

   
    private static final String VUFORIA_KEY =
            "ASe1QVf/////AAABmaGb2/L9xUlWgAL80CIHwEF9mGT3WO0uyNjWlgE3r6qkC5sdHUs7mUEiN7y0dvH/tfa1l4X5IKYztdASuRrIPZaD0uWzCn+jislTKPAEEOe7n+8QYOlzVjpWRCEP0jJJFKWubjWquTxYvDBpFe5sEK4" +
                    "88pJ6aB137BsPnRbSepXofymAh3bZF2Dm8UYfpzshmrs+4dmYs0tX" +
                    "QpUXIAdtjhrSGOxCo6PyGWRspJzBPe5C/C4Vhu2inV6wR1O+BzOp/CI0gdDp2nD5hjfdcK8Khlzpqa0C9gmhhnV+aQn19DAa/pm5E2Zb2kDq9romAmtK3ovEKHR+wHY9ix0p3+ZG9xSJUULEUWcvjID1ooipwDJ5";

    /**
     * {@link #vuforia} is the variable we will use to store our instance of the Vuforia
     * localization engine.
     */
    private VuforiaLocalizer vuforia;

    /**
     * {@link #tfod} is the variable we will use to store our instance of the TensorFlow Object
     * Detection engine.
     */
    private TFObjectDetector tfod;

    @Override
    public void runOpMode() {
        // The TFObjectDetector uses the camera frames from the VuforiaLocalizer, so we create that
        // first.
        initVuforia();
        initTfod();

        /**
         * Activate TensorFlow Object Detection before we wait for the start command.
         * Do it here so that the Camera Stream window will have the TensorFlow annotations visible.
         **/
        if (tfod != null) {
            tfod.activate();
        }

        /** Wait for the game to begin */
        telemetry.addData(">", "Press Play to start op mode");
        telemetry.update();
        waitForStart();

        if (opModeIsActive()) {
            while (opModeIsActive()) {
                if (tfod != null) {
                    // getUpdatedRecognitions() will return null if no new information is available since
                    // the last time that call was made.
                    List<Recognition> updatedRecognitions = tfod.getUpdatedRecognitions();
                    if (updatedRecognitions != null) {
                        telemetry.addData("# Object Detected", updatedRecognitions.size());
                        // step through the list of recognitions and display boundary info.
                        int i = 0;
                        for (Recognition recognition : updatedRecognitions) {
                            telemetry.addData(String.format("label (%d)", i), recognition.getLabel());
                            telemetry.addData(String.format("  left,top (%d)", i), "%.03f , %.03f",
                                    recognition.getLeft(), recognition.getTop());
                            telemetry.addData(String.format("  right,bottom (%d)", i), "%.03f , %.03f",
                                    recognition.getRight(), recognition.getBottom());
                        }
                        telemetry.update();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (tfod != null) {
            tfod.shutdown();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the Vuforia localization engine.
     */
    private void initVuforia() {
        /*
         * Configure Vuforia by creating a Parameter object, and passing it to the Vuforia engine.
         */
        VuforiaLocalizer.Parameters parameters = new VuforiaLocalizer.Parameters();

        parameters.vuforiaLicenseKey = VUFORIA_KEY;
        parameters.cameraName = hardwareMap.get(WebcamName.class, "Webcam 1");

        //  Instantiate the Vuforia engine
        vuforia = ClassFactory.getInstance().createVuforia(parameters);

        // Loading trackables is not necessary for the TensorFlow Object Detection engine.
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the TensorFlow Object Detection engine.
     */
    private void initTfod() {
        int tfodMonitorViewId = hardwareMap.appContext.getResources().getIdentifier(
                "tfodMonitorViewId", "id", hardwareMap.appContext.getPackageName());
        TFObjectDetector.Parameters tfodParameters = new TFObjectDetector.Parameters(tfodMonitorViewId);
        tfodParameters.minResultConfidence = 0.1f;
        //tfodParameters.isModelQuantized = true;
        tfodParameters.isModelTensorFlow2 = true;
        tfod = ClassFactory.getInstance().createTFObjectDetector(tfodParameters, vuforia);
        tfod.loadModelFromAsset(TFOD_MODEL_ASSET, LABEL_FIRST_ELEMENT);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @MattCiuzel, this [reference](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/convert) might help you in converting the Tensorflow model to tflite. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can converted with the python I use yolov5 to convert the .pt to the .tflite file. I am not sure that is the covert.py can using to convert between the tf2 to tf lite but the .pt is work. However I have the question is where do you put the model file to make the control hub recognition the image.

Comment: Open a separate question. Please don't go offtopic with the current one.